# Jquery Get parent element from data function

Tags: jquery

I need to get the parent element of a dataset function, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
<div id="test">

$('#test').data('func', {
  me: function() {
   console.log(this.parent())
  }
})

$('#test').data('func').me();
```

what I would like to return is `<div id="test">`

Of course, this does not work, but is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The `this` in your stored object loses the context of the initiating jQuery object and points, rather, to itself.

`this`, in the context of your `.data()` object, looks like:

```
{
  me: function() {
   console.log(this.parent())
  }
}
```

Your object doesn't inherit the jQuery prototype, so it does not have a `.parent()` method. And there isn't a clean way of getting — or providing — reference to the `$('#test')` from inside the `.data()` structure.

You can work around that — again, not as elegantly as you had wanted — by providing some sort of reference to `$('#test')` when you create the `.data()`…

```
$('#test').data('func', {
  $el: $( '#test' ),
  me: function() {
   console.log( this.$el[0] );
  }
});
```

This will get you the `<div id="#test">` element; at the cost of being dependent on explicitly referencing the element with each instance.

```js
$('#test').data('func', {
  $el: $( '#test' ),
  me: function() {
   console.log( this.$el[0] );
  }
});

$('#test').data('func').me();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You need to add the keyword `this` as `$(this)`

```js
$('#test').data('func', {
  me: function() {
   console.log($(this).parent())
  }
})

$('#test').data('func').me();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but that does not appear to return the parent element ?

Comment: You need this `<div id="test">` to be your output?